# What are {face,edge,vertex} normal projections of polyhedra?

Tags: polyhedra, projection

On the wikipedia page for a regular icosahedron they show  {face,edge,vertex} *normal* projections in addition to  {face,edge,vertex} projections, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron#Orthogonal_projections).

For example, here is the face normal projection

[image: face normal projection]

**My question is how are these defined?**

Comment: I found this nice page: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Polyhedra/icosahedron.shtml it looks like its just the icosahedron projected from different camera positions.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that there is a strict definition of these terms in the sense they are being used in these pics in Wikipedia.

For sure, you have 3 different elements in the icosahedron, any face, any edge, any vertex. So it would be better to speak of vertex-first projection (providing a decagonal picture), an edge-first and a face-first projection, as being seen in the very table of Wikipedia in the row above.

The mentioned pictures then are obtained by keeping the same axial alignments as above, but placing this axis into the paper plane, i.e. considering according side views. But note, this provides an one-parametric degree of rotational freedom for the orientation of such an arrangement.

--- rk